# Showing an array in a grouped table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

I have a JSON array like this:

```
Array = [{"type":"x", "name":"a1"}, 
         {"type":"x", "name":"a2"},
         {"type":"y", "name":"a3"},
         {"type":"y", "name":"a4"}]
```

Now, I'd like to show it in a table, using Angular, so that it takes this form:

```
x
a1
a2
y
a3
a4
```

The table shows the type and then the name of all the items which have that type.

Comment: Yikes. Settle down.

Comment: Do you have a fixed and small (2-3) number of types? Then you could create N tables with `ng-repeat` filtered by type. Otherwise, I suggest changing your array into a structure that accommodates how you want to display it. It's called "View Model" for a reason - it should model the View.

Comment: What did you do? Share your solution (that does not have to be working) so we can improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, wild man @Morre is correct (albeit a little excited about his correctness) that what you have is not a JSON array but rather an array of objects. But semantics aside...

While I'm confident there is a more elegant way of approaching your problem, here is one possible solution

```
// Given your array
var myArray = [{ 
    "type": "x",
    "name": "a1"
}, {
    "type": "x",
    "name": "a2"
}, {
    "type": "y",
    "name": "a3"
}, {
    "type": "y",
    "name": "a4"
}];

// create a new object structured like this
// {'x': ['a1', 'a2'], 'y': ['a2', 'a3']}
// while creating a new array that's structured like this
// ['x', 'a1', 'a2', 'y', 'a2', 'a3']
var newObj = {};
$scope.newArray = [];
myArray.map(function(obj) { 
    if (!newObj[obj.type]) {
        newObj[obj.type] = [obj.name];
        $scope.newArray.push(obj.type);
        $scope.newArray.push(obj.name);
    } else {
        newObj[obj.type].push(obj.name);
        $scope.newArray.push(obj.name);
    }
});
```

and your `ng-repeat` could look like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in newArray">
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
</tr>
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdr4w9c5/5/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngrepeat, however you would need to change your object structure such that "type" becomes a parent of "name":  `var obj = {type: 'x', names: [{name:'a1'}, {name:'a2'}]}`

OR

If you are dealing with a large dataset and cannot change the structure of your object for performance, you may want to consider writing an angular custom directive.